# Vagrant synced folder issue on windows?

Tags: windows, html, apache2, vagrant, atom-editor

I am using vagrant for development of a HTML5 app. I use Apache2 as web server. After I add some lines to my synced json file, my server serves unknown characteres at the end of the file instead of my changes. Any ideas why this strange behaviour happens?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about ?

Comment: sure. My project is synced to a virtual machine created by vagrant. After starting the virtual machine apache serves my html and json files without any problems. But after I make changes to a synced file, my server serves strange characteres (������������������) instead of my changes. After a reboot of the vm everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is an issue with sendfile protocoll when using vagrant with virtualbox: [vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html)

The "solution" is to disable sendfile in your webserver.